# column name and inverse column name in PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany, joincolumn

I want to give Column name and inverse column names of my join columns. However I am not sure how can I do it in case of  PrimaryKeyJoinColumn. Please help.

Below is the statement for PrimaryKeyJoinColumn

```
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pmr_provider_number", referencedColumnName = "pt_provider_number"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pmr_owner_access_key",referencedColumnName = "pt_owner_access_key"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pmr_owner_number",    referencedColumnName = "pt_owner_number"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "pmr_location_number", referencedColumnName = "pt_location_number")})
```

Below are the names of my columns

Join column names :

providermasterrecord_pmr_provider_number,

providermasterrecord_pmr_owner_access_key,

providermasterrecord_pmr_owner_number,

providermasterrecord_pmr_location_number_2038

Inverse column names:

listprovidertype_pt_providernumber,

listprovidertype_pt_owneraccesskey2464,

listprovidertype_pt_ownernumber2002,

listprovidertype_pt_servicelocationnumber2038

providermasterrecord and listprovidertype are name of objects. I want to give better names to the columns.

Since there are 4 classes involved I haven't provided classes details.

Comment: have you solved?